# Eliminating duplicate data in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am struck on this problem in java, and this is what i have so far.

A common problem in Computer Science is eliminating duplicate data. Write a program          that asks the user for a number between 1 and 100 (if not, ask them to try again).

- Next, if the number * entered has not been  entered before, keep track of it using an array.
- If the number has been entered before, inform the user and ask for another number.
- Your program should loop until the user has entered 10 unique numbers, then display the list of 10 numbers.
- Use an array of 10 elements to solve this.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Duplicate2_4_4 {
   public static void main(String[] args) { 

       //create an previous variable
       int previous = 0;
       //create an array
       int numArray[] = new int[10];
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Please enter 10 unique numbers between 1 to 100 ");
       numArray[previous] = keyboard.nextInt();

       if(numArray[ previous ] < 1 || numArray[ previous ] > 100)
           System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 to 100, try again ");

       for(int present = 0; present < numArray.length - 1; present++){
           if(numArray[ present ] < 1 || numArray[ previous ] > 100)
               System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 to 100, try again ");
           numArray[previous] = keyboard.nextInt();

           //keep track of user inputs
           for(int present1 = 0; numArray[present1] == numArray[previous]; present1++){               
               System.out.println("Please enter a unique number, try again ");
           }      

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. What's your question? Also, please properly format your code and question; it's extremely difficult to read it in its original state.

Comment: Why you are not using Set for this, if user enters duplicate value then add() method will return false

Comment: @siso - Because this is is a **beginners** programming exercise ... where the teacher obviously wants the students to learn to use arrays.

Comment: @StephenC ...without others doing the thinking/learning for them

Comment: @Bohemian - Precisely!

Answer (score 1):

We could easily write this for you, but that ultimately wouldn't help you learn to program ... which is (I assume) the reason you are doing this exercise/.

Therefore, I'll just give you some hints.

1. It will make your code simpler and easier (for you, and everyone else) to understand if you read the numbers into a temporary variable.  Don't put them into the array until *after* you have checked that they are in range.
2. Once you have checked the number is in range, you then need to check that you don't already have the number in the array.  Think about how you would do that.
3. Once you have determined that the number is not in the array, you need to put it into the array.  Think about *where* in the array you should put it.  (Obviously, it should NOT be in a slot that already contains a number ...)
4. A correct solution will (most likely) have one loop inside another loop.

Finally, it is worth noting that there are lots of ways to solve this problem.  Once you have found a solution that works ... and you understand that solution ... it may be worth while thinking about whether there is a simpler / more "elegant" way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by hashing technique

```
    int index[]=new int[101];
    int numArray[] = new int[10];
    int i=0;
    while(i<10)
    {
        int temp=keyboard.nextInt();
        if(index[temp]==0)
        {
             index[temp]=1;
             numArray[i++]=temp;
        }
        else System.out.println("This Number is already entered");
    }
```

Means you can keep track of numbers by taking an external array. Starting value of array's elements is `0` means it is not used and make it `1` means value is used.
In this hash function is **converting an integer value to an index and change the array value which is hashes or hash value to `1`**.

Comment: This is not "hashing" ...

Comment: It is just like hashing means we are converting an integer to index and retrieving its value in O(1).

Comment: No.  That's not what hashing means.  Hashing is converting some value into an integer.

Comment: @StephenC Kindly look at this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/) and read second line.

Comment: *"Kind of hashing"* is not hashing.  It is the author's shorthand way say "this is a bit like a hash table but it isn't really".  Read this page to understand what hashing really is.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: *"Hashing is converting some value into an integer."* - In fact it is more general than that.  But simply using an existing integer value as an index is NOT hashing.

Comment: My dear I don't care what do you think but I already read that wikipedia page. And On that page there is [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Hash_tables) concept which is similar to this implementation.And your first explanation said that the converting some value to integer is wrong if this is answer then you will get to know.

Comment: I don't care what you think either.  But I do care that you are spreading misinformation and bad terminology.  Kindly use the **accepted** terminology rather than scratching around for justifications for using bad terminology.  I don't intend to debate this further.  I've made my point and provided the evidence.

Comment: To students who are reading this Answer: BEWARE.  If you misuse the term "hashing" in an exam to describe array subscripting as Mr Devavrata does, your lecturer would be fully justified in deducting marks.

Comment: And Kindly to all those students who are going to listen Stephen C, please Don't believe on me but not also to him. He also said that **Hashing is converting some value into an integer** which is not true. This is kind of hashing and it is proved by [Geeks4Geeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/). A person with high reputation is not always correct.

Comment: I got this **-1** because Stephen C think it is not hashing but this code is correct to solve above problem.